# why socket recv keeps receiving data in a while loop, even if I don't send any data from sender

Tags: sockets, tcp, network-programming, blocking

Questions: 
1. why socket recv keeps receiving data in a while loop, even if I don't send any data from sender? isn't recv() a blocking function, I thought it blocks until tcp receives some data; 2. why numbytes = 0 ?

Below is the code, I just post the code of recv() and send(), I think other parts of the code works fine, but if you need all code to debug, please let me know I'll post them, Thanks!

```
 while(1) { //client receiving code
        if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE, 0)) == -1)
            perror("recv");
        }
        buf[numbytes] = '\0'; 
        printf("numbytes is %d\n", numbytes);   
        printf("client: received '%s'\n", buf); 
    }


while(1) { //server sending code
        char str[100];
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);

        if (new_fd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr), s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        while(1) {
            printf( "Enter a value :");
            scanf("%s", str);
            if (send(new_fd, str, 50, 0) == -1)
            perror("send");
        }
    }
```

Below is the screenshot of the result:
Input on the server terminal

```
Enter a value :123456
```

Output on the client terminal

```
numbytes is 0
client: received '12345'
numbytes is 0
client: received '6'
numbytes is 0
client: received ''
numbytes is 0
client: received ''
numbytes is 0
client: received ''
numbytes is 0
client: received ''
numbytes is 0
client: received ''
numbytes is 0
client: received ''
numbytes is 0
client: received ''
numbytes is 0
client: received ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're ignoring the possibility of a zero return from `recv()`, which means the peer has closed the connection, which means you must do so too, and stop reading.

Comment: Thanks, I get it, but how come numbytes is always 0, even if the client received '12345'?

Comment: The client *didn't* receive `12345`. It received zero bytes, which means end of stream. The stuff in the buffer is just left over from before.

Comment: Note that it's not possible for the client code to generate that output (because of the `buf[numbytes]='\0'`), so either that's not the real code, or it's not the real output.

Comment: @EJP so I should write a piece of code like this:  if (numbytes == 0) {close(sockfd); break;}, then this condition can be avoid?

Comment: @UI_jjw Isn't that exactly what it says in my answer?